# How to send addicional information along with ember Delete model request

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember model that I want to delete. So, according to the documentation I could do any of the following:

```
store.findRecord('post', 1, { backgroundReload: false }).then(function(post) {
        post.deleteRecord();
        post.get('isDeleted'); // => true
        post.save(); // => DELETE to /posts/1
    });
```

OR

```
store.findRecord('post', 2, { backgroundReload: false }).then(function(post) 
{
  post.destroyRecord(); // => DELETE to /posts/2
});
```

But, let's say that in order to delete the post model I need addicional information. For exemple, I also want to know the 'idAplication' (aplication sending delete  request) and 'userEmail' (user trying to delete post).

The problem is: by default the ember store will only send me the post id:
 `myapi.com/posts/1`

How can I do this ? How to send something else with the body delete request using ember model ?

Comment: you can always override the adapter and modify it. what you do sounds like some kind of authentication so you probably want to send the data for *every* request. So the adapter is a good place for this.

Comment: Its not authentication. I am using ember simple auth addon for this. The thing is I have this Post model that has an id, but this Post has several versions of itself on data base, so, in order to delete it I also need to know the post version Id. Its not like I need this in every request, only on DELETE.

Comment: So maybe it should be part of the id. But you can as I said just override the adapter

Comment: @TiagoConceiçao: That sound as you don't want to delete the entire post but a specific version of it. Did you considered using a specific endpoint for it instead? E.g. `/post-version/:id`. If you really want to go with you approach, have a look at `Model.destoryRecord()` method. There is an example [in it's documentation ](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.7/classes/DS.Model/methods/destroyRecord?anchor=destroyRecord) how to pass options to adapter. But as @Lux said, you need to customize your adapter to be able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When destroy record you can send some data as query string like DELETE `posts/2?applicationId=1234`.

To do that you can override how the *urlForDeleteRecord* is built in the model adapter, (or override the main app adapter to add the functionality for all models).

*app\adapters\application.js*

```
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';
// other imports ...

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  // other configurations ...

  urlForDeleteRecord(id, modelName, { adapterOptions: { data } }) {
    let queryString = data
      ? '?' + Object.keys(data).map(prop => `${prop}=${data[prop]}`).join('&')
      : '';

    return this._super(...arguments) + queryString;
  }
});
```

later in your code you can invoke the destroyRecord passing some data, like

```
store.findRecord('post', 2)
  .then((post) => { 
    post.destroyRecord({ adapterOptions: {
      data: {
        prop1: "value1",
        prop2: "value2"
      }
    }}); // => DELETE to /posts/2?prop1=value1&prop2=value2
  }
```

Comment: Thank U so much ! That's exactly what I was looking for :)